# Scala build settings(foobar: _*)

Tags: scala, sbt

I see this in `spray Build.scala`

```
lazy val sprayCaching = Project("spray-caching", file("spray-caching"))
    .dependsOn(sprayUtil)
    .settings(sprayModuleSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++=
      provided(akkaActor) ++
      compile(clHashMap) ++
      test(specs2)
    )
```

What does `.settings(sprayModuleSettings: _*)` do? Specifically `sprayModuleSettings: _*`.

Comment: If you are wondering what `: _*` means you should use [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/?q=scala+_*). It allows you to search on such symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.settings is a method that takes a variable argument list. sprayModuleSettings is a Seq. The : _* is to tell the compiler that you want to pass the elements in sprayModuleSettings as arguments to the method.

```
scala> val s = Seq(1,2,3,4)
scala> def test(args:Int*) { println(args.length) }
scala> test(s)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Int]
 required: Int
              test(s)
               ^

scala> test(s:_*)
4
```